# Creating the simplest menu with XNA 4.0 and C#

Tags: c#, xna

I am using XNA 4.0 and C# to create a game for the Windows PC, and I am having a problem creating the game's menu. I want to create the most simplest menu ever; a sidebar with a button on it, currently, the menu looks like that:

[image: The game's menu]

The menu is written in a .cs file, just like the game itself (I duplicated the fresh created .cs file that is being created with the project and renamed it), in the Solution Explorer, things look like that:

[image]

I just need a way to make the 'New Game' button trigger the game .cs file, and I have no idea how to do that, any thought?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not a good approach...

you should implement screen states... that way your menu will be a state (MenuScreenState), as your game will be other state (GameScreenState)....and this will let you implement more states like pause, victory, defeat,...

You can use as a base, this sample from microsoft:

http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/game_state_management

Comment: I just cant understand that sample! No matter how many times I tried, something is missing for me there, any explanation for that any where?

Comment: It's one of those "Learn by F11" samples.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure there's some nicer way of doing this. But couldn't you just hook an update loop to your menu and check if the mouse is clicking and is positioned within the button bounding box? Then if a click is registered on the button, set the game state to start the game.